# Incorrect login information showing on refresh: PHP LOGIN SCRIPT

Tags: php, authentication

Okay...so...my first question on here, please bear with me.

I have made a login script with registration, MySQL database, etc. So far it is working great. Except for the fact that when I refresh the page, even if I have not entered any information yet, it gives me the incorrect login information error. First time Loading the page, or if i log into a fake user, then log out, it will work. But Here is the code

```
    if($_SESSION["logged"])
{
         print_secure_content();
}
else {
        if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
        {  
        $_SESSION["logging"]=true;
        echo "Login:";
        loginform();
        }
         else if($_SESSION["logging"])
           {
                 $number_of_rows=checkpass();
                 if($number_of_rows==1)
                        {       
                         $_SESSION[user]=$_POST[userlogin];
                         $_SESSION[logged]=true;
                         echo"<h1>you have logged in successfully</h1>";
                         print_secure_content();
                        }
                else{
                                   echo "wrong password or username, please try again";
                                    loginform();



                        }
                }

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're storing whether or not to validate the username/password in the `$_SESSION`.

When the login form is shown, `$_SESSION['logging']` is set to `true`. Then, you log in successfully (and it's still set to true). The next time you see the login form, it's still set to `true`, so it attempts to check your username/password combination and thus the error.

Rather than using `$_SESSION['logging']` to determine whether or not you should validate the username/password, you should check for the existence of your username and password fields in the `$_POST` array, since these will be present only when the user submits the form.